# Snowflake - COPY INTO externalstage (Azure Storage) and compressing the file

Tags: download, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azcopy

Looking to confirm an issue I found with Downloading data from Snowfalke to external stage ( Azure ).  With compression set to 'gzip", ContentEncoding is not set and therefore AZCopy (used to transfer data) does not recognize the file as compressed and --decompress is not working.  Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Do a search on the error in this forum.

Comment: I do not get an error.  AZCopy does not recognize the file as compressed and therefore downloads it compressed.

Comment: I haven't heard of this one, and couldn't say whether this was a Snowflake issue or a Microsoft issue so I'd probably open a ticket on both sides. Do you normally have to set the ContentEncoding for Azure Blobs in other scenarios or does this automatically get populated? What actually controls how this field gets populated (is the Blob supposed to automatically detect or set the content encoding)?